# Происхождение и значение глаголов "прищучить" и "прижучить"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, глаголы, просторечия

*Как да во лесу дремучем

Что-нибудь да отчубучим,

Добра молодца **прищучим,**

И пограбим, и помучим!

...

 Ну-ка, рукава засучим,

Путника во тьме **прижучим,**

Свалим - и в песке зыбучем

Пропесочим и проучим!*
[**Владимир Высоцкий. Песня Соловья-Разбойника и его дружков**](http://v-vissotsky.ru/audio.php?zid=950)

ПРИЩУЧИТЬ, кого-что (*прост. фам.*).Сделать строгий выговор, строго пригрозить кому-нибудь. [*Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.*]
ПРИЩУ́ЧИТЬ,
*просторечие*.
То же, что прижучить.
[**[прищучить]**](https://www.google.ee/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&rlz=1C1AOHY_ruEE717EE717&oq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&aqs=chrome.4.69i59l2j0l4.10688j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
ПРИЖУ́ЧИТЬ,
*просторечие*.
Поймать с поличным, прижать; привлечь к ответу.
[**[прижучить]**](https://www.google.ee/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&rlz=1C1AOHY_ruEE717EE717&oq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6&aqs=chrome.2.69i59l3j69i57j0l2.8309j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Хотелось бы понять: как давно и каким образом в языке появились эти "животрепещущие" глаголы?
В каком значении они употребляются сегодня? И действительно ли - по значению - их можно приравнять друг к другу?

Comment: Не ущучил — почему "животрепещущие"?

Comment: Это я так, образно, ведь в кавычках же:  живые, трепещущие - щука и жук.

Answer (score 2):

Подобный вопрос нашла на просторах Интернета ([ссылка](http://vestnik-lesnoy.ru/prizhuchit-sistemu-prioritetov)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, продублируйте текст в теле ответа. Изображения применяются только в крайних случаях.