# Это такой жук, что

Tags: лексика, фразеология

Слышали **такое выражение**? А сами используете его и в каких случаях?

Почему же **именно жук**, или это к семейству жесткокрылых отношения не имеет?

Может, фонетика?  Я такой ***ж-ж-жук***, вот я вас уж-ж-жалю!

В Сети есть **фантазии** на эту тему, но разные. А вы как думаете?

Comment: Извините, а что означает это выражение?

Comment: Да разное означает, много вариантов Например  http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/293909-pro-kakogo-cheloveka-govorjat-chto-on-zhuk.html  https://france1950.livejournal.com/261365.html   https://otvet.mail.ru/question/26028725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох, ЖУК - это многогранный образ не относящийся конкретно к русской культуре.

Хотя жук имеется ввиду жук-навозник, он же скарабей.

Скарабея почитали египтяне. [*Жуку воздавали почести и считали его символом счастья.*](https://masterok.livejournal.com/1378644.html) - там прямо много про жуков, но мне понравилось вот это:

> Жуки, как самцы, так и самки, не только сами лепят шары, но и воруют и отнимают их друг у друга. Заполучив тем или иным образом шар, жук старается откатить его подальше, зарыть в землю и там, в уюте и спокойствии, предаться трапезе. Скарабей очень прожорлив, и вскоре ему приходится выбираться на поверхность за новой добычей.

У Эзопа есть басни про жуков:

*Жуки.*
*На островке пасся бык, а его навозом кормились два жука. Когда наступила зима, один жук сказал другому:*
*— Я хочу перелететь на берег, чтобы здесь тебе хватило корму; сам я перезимую там, а если найдётся много еды, то и тебе принесу.

Перелетел жук на берег, нашёл большую кучу свежего навоза и остался там кормиться. Прошла зима, и вернулся он на остров. Товарищ увидел, какой он жирный да крепкий, и стал его корить за то, что обещал, а ничего не принёс. Жук ответил:

— Не меня брани, а природу: место было такое, что есть было можно, а унести нельзя.

Эта басня относится к тем, **кто ласков, пока речь идёт лишь об угощениях, и бросает друга, когда нужно помочь чем-нибудь поважнее**.*

*Орёл и жук.

Орёл гнался за зайцем. Увидел заяц, что ниоткуда нет ему помощи, и взмолился к единственному, кто ему подвернулся — к навозному жуку. Ободрил его жук и, увидев перед собой орла, стал просить хищника не трогать того, кто ищет у него помощи. Орёл не обратил даже внимания на такого ничтожного заступника и сожрал зайца. Но жук этой обиды не забыл: неустанно он следил за орлиным гнездовьем и всякий раз, как орёл сносил яйца, он поднимался в вышину, выкатывал их и разбивал. Наконец орёл, нигде не находя покоя, искал прибежища у самого Зевса и просил уделить ему спокойное местечко, чтобы высидеть яйца. Зевс позволил орлу положить яйца к нему за пазуху. Жук, увидав это, скатал навозный шарик, взлетел до самого Зевса и сбросил свой шарик ему за пазуху. Встал Зевс, чтобы отрясти с себя навоз, и уронил ненароком орлиные яйца. С тех самых пор, говорят, орлы не вьют гнёзд в ту пору, когда выводятся навозные жуки.*

*Никого не должно презирать, ибо **никто не бессилен настолько, чтобы не отомстить за оскорбление**.*

*Осёл и цикады:*
*Осёл услышал, как стрекочут цикады. Понравилось ему их сладкое пение, стало ему завидно, и спросил он:

— Чем вы питаетесь, чтобы иметь такой голос?

— Росою, — ответили цикады.

Стал осёл и сам кормиться росою, но околел с голоду.*

Муравей и жук(ну это все слышали):
*В летнюю пору гулял муравей по пашне и собирал по зернышку пшеницу и ячмень, чтобы запастись кормом на зиму. Увидал его жук и посочувствовал, что ему приходится так трудиться даже в такое время года, когда **все остальные животные отдыхают от тягот и предаются праздности**.

Промолчал тогда муравей; но когда пришла зима и навоз дождями размыло, остался жук голодным, и пришел он попросить у муравья корму.

Сказал муравей:

«Эх, жук, кабы ты тогда работал, когда меня трудом попрекал, не пришлось бы тебе теперь сидеть без корму».*

*Так люди в достатке не задумываются о будущем, а при перемене обстоятельств терпят жестокие бедствия.*

Забавно, что из басен про осла и цикад и про муравья и жука получилась в итоге одна басня. Однако, ослик-то сдох.

Вот эта еще забавная, жук-навозник пересекается с фекальной тематикой и всяким дурным нравом:

*Зевс и Лиса.

Зевс, восхищаясь умом и хитростью лисицы, поставил ее царем над неразумными животными. Но ему хотелось узнать, с переменой судьбы переменилась ли у лисицы и низкая ее душа?

И вот, когда ее несли в носилках, он выпустил перед нею жука; жук закружился над носилками, а лиса, не в силах сдержаться, позабыла всякую царскую честь, выскочила из носилок и бросилась его ловить.

Разгневался Зевс и обратил лисицу в ее прежнее состояние.

Басня показывает, что дурные люди даже среди пышности и блеска не меняют своего нрава.*

Еще на ум приходит песня [La Cucaracha](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F)). Ну и [Превращение](https://xn----7sbb5adknde1cb0dyd.xn--p1ai/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/) Кафки.

А что Даль пишет:

> По-бычьи мычит, по-медвежьи рычит, наземь падет, землю дерет? Жук.

> Жуку нора за обычай. Подле пчелки в медок, а подле жука - в навоз. Как жук в навозе копается. Зарылся, как жук в навоз. Только жук, в навозе живучи, да чисто обихаживается. И у жука рог, да петушьего бодня не стоит.

> Жукленок муж. малый ребенок. Все ушли на работу, до последнего жукленка. Вообще, жук и прозвоизводные его, дают понятие о жужжании, о жизни и о черноте: Хожу я по топотихе, загляну я в жукотиху, в жукотихе топыра, грохотихою укрыта? пол, чело печи, дрова, печь.

Жуки - простой люд, чернь, копающиеся в навозе, выращивающий себе что-то из навоза, отличающийся низким моральным статусом, живучестью, изворотливостью, индивидуализмом, но при этом глупый и недальновидный, довольствующийся малым, но при этом счастливый.

Какая-то литературщина вышла)

Comment: Спасибо! А я думала, что жуком мало кто интересуется. Мне больше нравятся бронзовые жуки, они уж точно не навозные.  "Как-то летом на лужайке
Господин учитель Жук
Основал для насекомых
Школу чтенья и наук" (Константин Льдов).    Видите, жук умный.  А это современная поэзия (А. Усачев):  "Шёл по улице жучок
В модном пиджачке.
На груди блестел значок,
А на том значке
Нарисован был жучок,
Тоже в пиджачке... " И т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Используем, и частенько.

[Жук](https://russian_argo.academic.ru/3727/%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0), жуча́ра — жадный, скупой, прижимистый человек.

> В системе национального русского языка закрепилось известное большинству носителей образное употребление номинации «жук» для обозначения таких качеств человека, как хитрость или жадность. <...>
> Зооним «жук» культурно обусловлен, о чем говорит частота использования данной лексемы в метафорическом ключе и близость значений, выявляемых в каждом отдельном случае употребления.
> Так, центральным смыслом является человеческая хитрость, с которой связаны такие характеристики личности, как склонность к обману, ловкость и изворотливость. В языковой картине мира эти свойства являются отрицательными и осуждаемыми обществом, поскольку, во-первых, связаны с ложью, во-вторых, сопутствуют личному успеху, в противовес присущей русской культуре черте коллективности.

П р и м е р ы (значение чувствуется сразу)

• Но, наверное, есть и **такие жуки**, которые стараются урвать для себя побольше (Михаил Божаткин. Флаг на гафеле).
• Гад, пьяница, чудик, подстрекатель, **жучара тот еще**... но такой родной (Дарья Симонова. Шанкр).
• Есть **такие жучки**, охмурят девушку, а потом бросят (Даниил Гранин. Искатели).
• **Ну и жуки**! Пронякин только отбыл в ИОНХ, они тут же притащили в дьюаровском сосуде пять литров пива и в муфеле шашлыка нажарили – красота... (Аркадий Вайнер, Георгий Вайнер. Лекарство против страха).
• **Ну и жук** этот Фолкнер! Украл, паскуда, мой сюжет!.. (Сергей Довлатов. Ремесло).

Статья об **энтомониме** "жук" (цитирование — из нее):
[Зооморфная метафора как отражение русской языковой картины мира](http://izvestia.vspu.ac.ru/content/izvestia_2019_v285_N4/Izv%20VGPU%202019%20Issue%204%20(285)_185-189.pdf).

P. S. И интересуемся. Я задавала схожий (жучий, жучиный?) вопрос:
[Происхождение и значение глаголов "прищучить" и "прижучить"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431893/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, прекрасный ответ!  Я, может, позже напишу комментарий в ответе. Голоса от меня за две темы.